# How to create a graph from German OSM data with OSMnx efficiently?

Tags: python, graph, osmnx, distance-matrix

I am currently working on a dataset with German postal codes. I aim to calculate "real" distances between the centers of each postal code area. To do so, I first downloaded the germany-latest.osm.bz2 file from geofabrik. Next I would like to create a graph from the downloaded file for the network_type = "driving".

However, I noticed that using the osmnx.graph.graph_from_xml() method is very time consuming for a large OMS file such as for Germany.

My questions are:

1. How can I create the graph more efficiently?
2. Once the graph has been created: how can I compute the "real" distances for a large set of origin-destination-pairs?

Thank you!

I am attaching my current code for reference:

```
import os
from pyrosm import OSM, get_data
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

os.chdir(r"myPath")

xml = "germany-latest.osm.bz2"

graph = ox.graph.graph_from_xml(xml) #how to restrict to network_type = "driving"?
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to download each country separately with https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html and save them to a PostGIS Database with osm2psgl (https://osm2pgsql.org/).

Setting up a PostGIS DB is done fast and working with osm2psgl is easier than it looks as well.

You can upload a bz2 File to your PostGIS DB from geofabrik with:

```
osm2pgsql bayern.osm.bz2 -d geodb -U USERNAME -W -H localhost -P 5432 -S default.style --output-pgsql-schema=osm --prefix bayern
```

When it's uploaded to PostGIS you can use all the PostGIS SQL magic you need.

Comment: I am new to postGIS and have had a look around in its documentation, but could you explain or point me to an explanation on how I could use the PostGIS sql to reduce the original osm file to the driving network only?

I'm face with the same issue as the OP but with the UK

Comment: yea sure! SELECT * FROM uk_line WHERE highway = "path" AND WHERE highway = "residential" ... and so on you d have to add all tags relevant to you here. uk_line is the table name of the line geometries of roads, paths and footwalks when you use osm2pgsql

Comment: thankyou very much. this points me in the right direction for the same use case as the OP